# How to use command prompt to list file names in directory but exclude 1st 3 characters

Tags: vba, batch-file, command-line, command-prompt

I'm trying to write some vba code that sends a line of code to the command prompt and executes it. I have that part down, but I need help getting the actual code to work.

I want to list all of the files in a specific folder that are the `.doc` file extension, but I want to exclude the first three characters of the filename that gets printed to my output text file. (Note: I'm using vba because this is one of several different commands I'd like to get into a single vba macro, and I cannot use batch files b/c they are blocked on my system so I'd like to work directly with the command prompt)

The following code works and gives me the file names without the file extension (ie. `ABC201704.doc` will return as `ABC201704`)

```
*%comspec% /c for %i in (C:\Test\ABC*.doc) do @echo %~ni >> C:\Test\Output.txt*
```

However, I don't know how to modify this so that it doesn't include the first 3 characters (ie. I'd like it to return `201704` instead of `ABC201704`).

Any help would be greatly appreciated! I tried using the following link, but I couldn't figure out how to get that to work for my situation.

Comment: Do you need the results in command prompt particularly? There are many ways to list files in VBA, using command prompt is quite unusual.

Comment: My end goal is to list my results in a text file. The files are located on a server, and I did come up with some vba code that does what I want, but it takes substantially longer than I'd like.  The code I listed in my question takes about 30 seconds to run, while the work around I tried using only vba and the file system object (FSO) functionality takes maybe 45 minutes because I'm cycling through 30,000 files. Given I'll be doing this many times, I'd like to have it be as quick as possible, and it seems that the command prompt is the quickest at doing that somehow

Comment: Ok thanks, I was going to suggest the FSO. I'd be really interested in the timing comparisons if you get a suitable answer here, would you mind posting the results?

Comment: Yes I'll absolutely post my results, I tried posting my vba code here to share but it seems it's too many characters long

Comment: Ah, maybe that's the issue... you can get file paths with just a few lines of code. Generally the FSO is pretty quick, 45 mins does seem excessive. Can you post just the relevant part?

Comment: Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(InputFolder)

'Specify stream type - want to save text/string data
fsT.Type = 2
'Specify charset for the source text data
fsT.Charset = "utf-8"
'Open the stream and write binary data To the object
fsT.Open

'Loop through each file in the folder
For Each objFile In objFolder.Files

If Left(objFile.Name, 3) = "EPA" And Right(objFile.Name, 4) = ".001" Then
  'Write to the stream
  fsT.WriteText Mid(objFile.Name, 4, 5) & vbNewLine
End If
      
Next objFile

Save binary data to disk
fsT.SaveToFile OutputFile, 2

'Close the stream
fsT.Close

Comment: Dang that didn't post in a very reader-friendly format, sorry about that

Comment: No probs. Yeah, that's pretty efficient already, the only change I'd suggest is putting the file name to a string then using your Left and Right functions on that instead of the objFile.Name, might save a bit of time. Maybe also store the results in an array rather than write to the txt file every line, then write it all in one go at the end. I'll be watching the answers you get!

Comment: I'm not very experienced using arrays. Do you have a snippet of code how I would do that for each file?

Comment: Dim files() as string Dim fileNo as Long FileNo = 0 Redim files(objFolder.Files.Count) If Left 'etc Then files(fileNo) = objFile.Path fileNo = fileNo + 1

Comment: Almost done modifying the code to use arrays. Last question: I have my array set up and populated, how do I print that to my text file with each one on a new line?

Comment: Here you go: Dim x as Long For x = 0 to Ubound(files) If not IsEmpty(files(x)) then fsT.WriteLine files(x) Next x

Comment: Looks like it runs 25% faster with those modifications, but the command prompt solution is by far the quickest.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not tested:

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion

for %%a in ("C:\Test\ABC*.doc") do (
   set docname=%%~nxa
   echo !docname:~3!
)
```

In command prompt:

```
cmd /v:on  /c "for %a in  ("C:\Test\ABC*.doc") do set  docname=%~nxa & echo !docname:~3!"
```

Comment: It looks the cmd prompt says the syntax is incorrect when I tried that

Comment: @ampsoccer17 - can you try again?

Comment: Typo, remove the first or second instance of `in` and the same with `set`. `cmd /c /v:on for %a in ("C:\Test\ABC*.doc") do set docname=%~nxa & echo !docname:~3!`

Comment: @Compo - turned out the whole command needs to be in quotes also

Comment: Ok so now we're extremely close. It successfully removed the first 3 characters, but it includes the file extension, and I just need it to not include the extension

Comment: If I remove the "x" from docname=%~nxa it looks like it works!

Comment: @npocmaka @compo - thanks for the help it works like a charm and takes less than a minute which is perfect! After substituting in my vba variables, my final vba code looks like this: `command = "%comspec% /v:on  /c ""for %a in  (""" & Input_Path & "ABC*.doc"") do set  docname=%~na & echo !docname:~3! >> " & Output_Path & Output_Name & ".txt"""`